# Reversing the Feature Scaling of scale( ) in R

Tags: r, feature-scaling

## Short Question

> How to **revers** or **revert** the feature scaling done in R using `scale()` or is there any other suitable feature scaling method.

## Long Question

#### Feature Scaling

Feature scaling in R is done with following method,

```
dataset <- matrix(1:40, ncol = 4)
dataset.scaled <- scale(dataset, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
```

which will scale the dataset.

#### Un Scaling

according to several sources [eg](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DMwR/versions/0.4.1/topics/unscale) states to unscale the scaled matrix use

```
dataset.unscaled <- unscale(dataset.scale)
```

but when executed it says

> Error in unscale(X.scaled) : could not find function "unscale"

Comment: The `unscale` function you link is from the package `DMwR`, have you installed this package and loaded it before calling the `unscale` function?

Comment: I think problem is with my R system then, the package DMWR is not working in R version 3.6.3, Thank you very much.